# Iframe embedded video does not loop anymore

Tags: youtube-api

We've got an application running which uses `//youtube.com/embed/`, `&playlist=VIDEO_ID,VIDEO_ID` and `&loop=1`, this worked perfectly until recently (no code changes in this application for a long time). Somehow Youtube ends the playback at the end of the playlist and shows related video's. I'd expect that setting `&rel=0` might have some influence, though this actually resulted in the video just stopping.

Is there any API change that I need to apply to get this working again? I can't find anything... Fun fact is that when using the AS3 version `//youtube.com/v/` with the same values, everything works just fine as it used to!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this value is only supported on AS3 player as stated in here: https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters#loop

As YouTube is defaulting to HTML5, that's why it's breaking for you now.
http://youtube-eng.blogspot.com/2015/01/youtube-now-defaults-to-html5_27.html

Comment: Ah well that explains it. Sounds like they will fix the HTML5 version in the future, can you confirm this by any chance? Thanks anyway! I'll be using the AS3 (/v/) for the longer run for now then.

Comment: Just ran into this as well. To add to this answer, it appears the March 9th update broke it by disallowing <object> embeds, which it was probably falling back to when the "loop" or "playlist" params were present. Currently  looking into looping manually as it seems this is the only way.

Comment: Hi @Andrew, do you have any snippet to show that shows how that manual looping works? I'm really wondering if this will be fixed in the future..

Comment: Basically just listen to an "onStateChange" event, and when the state is YT.PlayerState.ENDED use player.seekTo(0)